Shopify Hydrogen: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET - Cannot reach development server on local machine (localhost:3000) after running npm run dev
Note: I'm on Windows 10, running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, WSL.
Hi, I'm trying to get started with learning Shopify Hydrogen and creating a storefront. I have followed Shopify's guide here: https://shopify.dev/docs/storefronts/headless/hydrogen/getting-started
I have created a new storefront project directory with npm create @shopify/hydrogen@latest -- --quickstart
I then did npm run dev to run the development server, which seemingly is running okay, if my command line is anything to go by: Image of command line

> hydrogen-quickstart@2024.7.3 dev
> shopify hydrogen dev --codegen


Environment variables injected into MiniOxygen:

SESSION_SECRET   from local .env

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:3000/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h + enter to show help


╭─ success ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                                              │
│  View Hydrogen app: http://localhost:3000/ [1]                               │
│                                                                              │
│  View GraphiQL API browser:                                                  │
│  http://localhost:3000/graphiql                                              │
│                                                                              │
│  View server network requests:                                               │
│  http://localhost:3000/subrequest-profiler                                   │
│                                                                              │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
[1] http://localhost:3000/


However, whenever I try to access the development server at localhost:3000 in my browser (any browser, Chrome, Firefox, all return the same issue), nothing loads. In Chrome, I get a "This site can't be reached" - ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error: Chrome browser error: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
This issue is exclusively happening to me with Shopify Hydrogen. I haven't encountered any issues with running local development servers with other applications, e.g. Vite with React, Next.js - those are all working.
If anyone has any ideas about what I can do to resolve this issue, I would appreciate it.
Thanks.
